# Collapsible doesn't work with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to insert content from a database with ajax in a collapsible set (jquery mobile). My problem is that the collapsible thing is currently not working. It's stucked in closed position and my search-filter can't search in.

I'm no sure about my event on the loading of page (sometimes my collapsible disapear from the page, when I'm coming from another one per example). I have doubts about the refresh of the div in the bottom too.

Also, if you have code recommendations. Maybe there is a better way to do this.

```
$homeDir = "http://localhost:8888/media";
$(document).on("pageinit ", "#informatique", afficherBranche);

function afficherBranche() {

    // Chargement des classes et des informations y relatives
    $.ajax({
        url: $homeDir + "model/getdata.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        // en cas de succès
        success: function (data) {
            $("#collapsiblesetForFilter").empty(); // Vide le contenu de la LV
            // Parcours de l'objet jSon
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#collapsiblesetForFilter").append('<div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-filtertext="HTML programmation web" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-first-child ui-collapsible-collapsed">' + '<h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">' + '<a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-inherit ui-icon-plus">' + data[i]["titre"] + '<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>' + '</a></h3>' + '<div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">' + '<p>' + data[i]["description"] + '</p></div></div>');
            }
        },
        error: function () { }
    });
    $('#collapsiblesetForFilter').collapsibleset().trigger('create');
};
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `$( ".selector" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );` after ajax success? like: `$.ajax({/*blah*/, success : function(data) { /*do stuff*/; $('#collapsiblesetForFilter').collapsibleset( "refresh" );}});`

Comment: Can you post a simpel JSON output we can use to recreate your example?

Comment: Thanks for help. Yep moving the refresh helped a lot. 

Also, the all code I put in the append were duplicated since I refreshed it correctly. So I removed some classes in my div, the <a> and the <span> and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coderecommendations:

1. Trye using deferred because callbacks are depricated. Follow the link and search for "Deprecation" and you will have the note and above how to use it. [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

   Basically it is $.ajax(..).done(function success() {}).fail(function error() {});

I don't speak french, so i'm not sure what is wrong, but i guess that your last line should also be called only on success, shouldn't it?
That yould mean that you just have to move this line after your for-loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As you said, moving up this line helped a little.

$('#collapsiblesetForFilter').collapsibleset().trigger('create');


So instead of using succes I should use .done and instead of error it's fail ? 

Let's see if it works :)

Comment: Yes. .fail() is the equivalent to the error-callback. Deferred is also chanable. You could do "$.ajax(...).then(dosomething else which could fail).done(whatever).fail()". This would cause the function given to then to execute after successfull ajax call, done if the then function worked and fail() if anything failed before. (as far as i understood it.. but i hadn't had a case to test this)